# Spacing before align environment

Tags: math-mode, spacing, amsmath

I am working with the exam class, and need to align some solutions.  However, I would like to move the align environment up, so that it is on the same line as the question/part number.  Is this possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `aligned` environment instead. It produces aligned multicolumn formulas in inline math mode, so it doesn't begin a new paragraph. Use `aligned` within `\( ... \)` or `$ ... $` following the question/part number.

Comment: If you want the first line of the `aligned` environment to line up with the line of the question, you should use `$\begin{aligned][t]` (i.e., the optional argument `[t]` says to align the first line of the environment with the surrounding line).

Comment: Thank you both very much!  That is exactly what I was after!